# How to estimate numerically a lim sup/lim inf

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, approximation, limsup-and-liminf, simulation

Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $X_n$ s.t. $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=c$ a.s. For example, we could take the $X_n$ to be the sample mean from some well-behaved distribution.

If I have a way of generating values for the $X_i$ and want to estimate the value of $c$, then, say, $X_{10^5}$ is likely to be a decent approximation for $c$. I could, for example, plot a graph of values for $X_1,\dots,X_{10^5}$ and hopefully it should be pretty apparent what the value of $c$ approximately is.

My question is if instead I have $\limsup_{n\to\infty}X_n=c$ a.s. (or with $\liminf$), how can I approximate $c$?

In this case, $X_{10^5}$ is of course not necessarily a good approximation. Would something like $\max_{i\leq10^5}X_i$ be better (or $\min$ if we have $\liminf$)?

Comment: $\limsup a_n = \sup \mathrm{A},$ where $\mathrm{A}$ is the set of accumulation points of the sequence $(a_n).$ In this case, I suspect you will need to see a plot of $X_n$ and see where they overlap. So, the horizontal axis will be the values of $X_n$ and the vertical axis does not represent much but can be used to jitter the picture and more visually see where the clusters occur.

Comment: by the way, if $X_n \to c$ and you can sample the values of $X_n$ for any $n,$ obviously you want to sample $X_{10^5}$ only if $n = 10^5$ is your largest avaliable index to sample from...

Comment: @WilliamM. I don't quite understand what kind of plot you are suggesting? (And of course, agree with the second point)

Comment: Okay, plot $n \mathrm{vs.} X_n$ and draw horizontal lines that will pass "near" many poins (the "ordinate" of these horizontal lines correspond to the set $\mathrm{A}$ and the largest of these ought to be an approximation of $\limsup$). If $X_n = (-1)^n + \mathrm{small\ noise},$ you should end up with many points around the lines $y = -1$ and $y = 1,$ and the limit of suprema will be the "ordinate" (a.k.a. "y-value") of these lines.

Comment: @WilliamM. ok this makes sense I guess. Far from an exact science, of course, but probably the best I could hope for.

Comment: It might be possible to use something like $\operatorname{max}_{10^5 \le i \le 10^6} X_i$ as an approximation to the lim sup.